# What is the relevance of "for all $x$" in this epsilon-delta definition, rather than just having a single $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

I am wondering what the relevance of the "for all $x$" part of the epsilon-delta definition of limit is and whether this would be a different definition if we had only a single $x$ for which if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$- **would there be any function which approaches a certain limit at a certain point according to this modified epsilon-delta definition with a single $x$, but which doesn't approach this limit according to the standard epsilon-delta definition?** The definition I am referencing is the below one:

> The function $f$ approaches the limit $l$ near $a$ means: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

I am wondering this because Spivak's provisional definition of a limit was

> The function $f$ approaches the limit $l$ near $a$, if for every number $\varepsilon>0$ we can make $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$ by requiring that $|x-a|$ be sufficiently small, and $x \neq a$.

This makes it sound as if a single value for $x$ is necessary to make the distance between $f(x)$ and $l$ within $\varepsilon$, leading me to question whether these are the same, and what the relevance of the 'for all' is in the stand epsilon-delta definition.

EDIT: due to the comments, I now see that Spivak wasn't talking about a single $x$ satisfying that condition; would there be any function which approaches a certain limit at a certain point according to this modified epsilon-delta definition with a single $x$, but which doesn't approach this limit according to the standard epsilon-delta definition, so that I can understand the relevance of the "for all $x$".

Comment: What Spivak means is that for all $x\not = a$ for which $|x-a|$ is sufficiently small, one has $|f(x)-l|< \varepsilon$.

Comment: "by requiring that |x-a| be sufficiently small" would imply that *any* x making that sufficiently small will have the property mentioned. So this is a case where the universal quantifier, though not explicitly mentioned, nonetheless is implied by the wording. The only way to avoid all ambiguity would be the other version you mention, and the wording here is just meant to give an intuitive feeling to what the precise version says.

Comment: Another way to express the "for all $x$": For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x$ *that satisfies that* $0<|x-a|<\delta$, one has that $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Heuristically, for any "vertical" $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $L$, there exists a "horizontal" $\delta$-neighborhood of $a$, the *entirety* of which the function $f$ maps into that neighborhood of $L$, *with the possible exception of $a$ itself*. If we only required $f$ to map a *single* point in neighborhood of $a$ into the neighborhood of $L$, then we could assert that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ equals any value taken on by $f$, *anywhere*, by choosing a suitably large $\delta$-neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a function for which the limit at a certain point is something according to the real epsilon delta definition, but is something else according to the modified version where it is only a single $x$
> satisfying that condition

When all $x$ in a neighborhood satisfy the condition, it follows that there is one $x$ there that satisfies the condition, so such example cannot be found.

However, it is possible that the limit does not exist, but the modified definition with "there exists $x$ such that ... and ..." instead of "for all $x$, if ... then ..." is satisfied. Namely, let $f(x)$ be $0$ everywhere except for at the points $1,1/2,1/3,1/4\ldots$, where it is equal to $1$. Such a function has a "limit" of $1$ (and also $0$ too) at $x=0$ according to the modified definition, while according to the actual definition of the limit it has no limit at that point.

The condition "there exists $x$ such that if ..., then ..." is not interesting because we can always make it true by choosing an $x$ which does not satisfy the "if" condition and therefore satisfies the implication.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to the question and similar in spirit to @colt_browning's excellent answer, but here is an example with limits at infinity (which I believe are more intuitive than limits at some number $a$):

Consider $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Then, for every $M>0$, there exists $x>M$ such that $f(x)=0$. But, of course, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)\neq 0$.